# What is the preferred way for a thread to communicate with the object that created it?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an object that creates 10 threads.
That object has a collection of Users.
Each of those threads can either check to see if a specific user exists, or can add/remove users from the collection.

I'm wondering as to how I should implement that communication.

Should I pass the collection of users into each thread via constructor or a method inside the threads?

Should I pass the main object into each thread so they can access the object's properties? Or maybe have specific methods inside the main object for handling the user collection that the threads will call?

I'm not sure what is the best practice in that situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to keep your User objects in a thread safe data structure, this will ensure that your threads don't encounter any race conditions during addition/removal of user objects.

You should take a look at the [Concurrent Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html) offered by java. You could also use a synchronized version of a standard java collection obtained via `Collection.synchronizedCollection` see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection%28java.util.Collection%29)

It's fine to pass that data structure into the constructor of each thread so that you have access to the collection within each thread.

Comment: I understand I need a thread safe structure. But that is not what the question is about. What I'm asking is basically the pros/cons of either: A: Pass the structure to the threads, or B: declare the structure public and pass the entire object to the threads, and then the threads could do something like: `this.parentObject.users.add(...)`. Im specifically asking if B is okay if sometime later I need to do use some other object's structures so maybe it's bad practice to pass every single structure to the threads?

Comment: Ok so if I'm understanding you correctly you are asking whether it is better to pass the data structure to each Thread via a constructor (A) or whether you should just allow them to access the data structure by either declaring it public or having a getter method for it (B)?

I guess that depends on what you think is best in terms of where you see the project developing in future. Yes if you think you are going to need to access many collections from the parent class then having the structures public/using getters may be best (option B).

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding is correct, you need a structure which should be threadsafe so that any thread can add and remove user. I will suggest you to use `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList` which should contain users. It should be something like this.

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<User> copwl = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

Here user is an object.

If you want, you can pass this above list to threads.

Comment: Yes, you can pass in thread's constructor. You can write small thread program to check.

Comment: Okay. What if I needed to notify the object that created the threads to do something, is it then okay to pass the object reference into every thread so they can call on its (the object that created them) methods? Im not sure if you understand me

Comment: I could not get what you said in the above comments.

Comment: As a side note, using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is usually preferable if you are iterating over the list more than you are writing to it, if you are going to be creating and writing a lot of new users you may want to consider a different type of object